# How to check WooCommerce order meta before sending email notification

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm trying to add custom meta to my new order emails. At this moment, custom meta shows up when I use the "Resend new order notification", but it doesn't when a purchase is made through the website.

I suspect this has to do with my code not being able to check the Order Details before sending the email notification. Here's the code I came up with so far..

```
// Ref: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-extra-content-order-email/

function custom_order_type_number_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    
    // Get custom Order Type and Order Number meta keys
    $custom_order_type = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'custom_order_type', true );
    $custom_order_number = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'custom_order_number', true );
    
    // Add for New Order email notification only
    if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {
        if ( !empty( $custom_order_type ) ) {
            echo '<p><b>Order type :</b> ' . $custom_order_type . '</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p><b>Order type :</b> Website</p>';
        }
        
        if ( !empty( $custom_order_number ) ) {
            echo '<p><b>Order no :</b> ' . $custom_order_number . '</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p><b>Order no :</b> New</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'custom_order_type_number_email', 20, 4 );
```

What I'm trying to do ideally is..

When the customer purchases from the website, this new order will be without the custom meta. So the custom meta in the email will show Order type: Website / Order number: New.

And if the admin manually adds a new order with defined custom meta, this new order email notification would get and show the saved custom meta later.

I hope this made sense. (>_<) And thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: _"I suspect this has to do with my code not being able to check the Order Details before sending the email notification"_ - This isn't the case, it's just that the meta data doesn't exist yet because you will only add it afterwards. I therefore do not understand your question, since an if/else condition has already been added in your current code that handles this

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thanks for the response. Let me try to describe it better below..

If there is no meta data yet, then I want to show..
Order type: Website
Order number: New

If the meta data exists, then it should show..
Order type: Meta data value
Order number: 1234 (manually entered text)

The only time this meta data would exist is when the site owner (admin) either manually adds a new order, or edit an existing order and update.

I hope this better clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.